# Add a button foreach row of a listview layout

Tags: javascript, custom-button, list-view

In the search result layout of the Product2 module, I need to add a custom  button for each row of the listview. The button will execute some javascript, do an ajax call and open a jquery ui dialog box.

Is it possible, in a professional edition environment, to do this thing?
I thought to use a custom formula field to create the button, but I discovered that custom formula can't execute javascript.

For the time being the only solution I have found is to create a custom visualforce page so I can print a javascript button for each row.

Comment: I think custom visualforce is how to do it. At least that was my first thought

Comment: The formula as a hyperlink would be best. Just pass the parameters to a VF page that runs the javascript. You dont need to override the list page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom button(list button) with display checboxes, and insert your javascript logic.

After create the custom button, you can edit the search layout and add your button.

You button will be in the header of Product table, but you will have check to select the record.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your input fields and command buttons in apex repeat or in a pageBlockTable

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
 <apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="acc">
 <apex:inputField value="{!acc.name}"/>
 <apex:CommandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>
 </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```